# Ant build: ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, ant

I am trying to build (through the command line) using the following components:

Ant version: 1.7.1
Java version: 1.3

However, I'm getting the following error message:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tools.ant.Main
```

Another interesting issue is that I get the same error when I write the following command in the command line:
`ant -v`

However, when I use Java 1.6* then this error does not appear.

What could be the cause if this error?

Comment: may be java version not supporting can you try with 1.4

Comment: I must use java 1.3 in this particular build

Answer (score 0):

The problem was quite tricky. The path to my ant contained the letter "ö". This could for some reason not be interpreted correctly when building with JDK1.3. Below are some guidelines if you have a similar problem:

1. Make sure that the path to your Ant and JDK does not contain non-english caracters such as: å,ä,ö.
2. Ensure that you input the following value in the Path variables (under system variables): %ANT_HOME%\bin
3. If not done automatically when installing Ant, create a user variable called ANT_HOME. In there you specify the path to your Ant directory.
4. Ensure that the system variable CLASSPATH contains the path to your Ant folder.